# How to Detect Whether Robot Caused Event in Java?

Tags: java, javafx, camera, awtrobot

I'm trying to create a `mouselook system` for a first-person game using `JavaFX`. Right now, I have an `onMouseMoved` event handler, running a number of camera-related commands.

However, because the mouse is moving I want to return it to the center of the screen. As such, I use an `AWT Robot` to align it dead in the middle of the user's display.

Everything I've done works, but the **problem is** that the Event handler sees the Robot's return of the cursor to the centre of the screen as movement and then returns the camera to its natural position.

Does anyone know how I might be able to detect whether a Robot caused the event, within the handler itself?

```java
scene.setOnMouseMoved(event -> {
    if (!returning) {
        if (MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x > mousePos.x) {
            camera.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(5, camera.getFieldOfView() / 2, camera.getFieldOfView() / 2, camera.getFieldOfView() / 2, Rotate.Y_AXIS));
            camrot += 5;
            if (camrot > 360) {
                camrot -= 360;
            }
            System.out.println(camrot);
            camera.getTransforms().removeAll();
            mousePos = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
        } else if (MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x < mousePos.x) {
            camera.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(-5, camera.getFieldOfView() / 2, camera.getFieldOfView() / 2, camera.getFieldOfView() / 2, Rotate.Y_AXIS));
            camrot -= 5;
            if (camrot < 0) {
                camrot += 360;
            }
            System.out.println(camrot);
            camera.getTransforms().removeAll();
            mousePos = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
        }

        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.mouseMove(defaultPos.x, defaultPos.y);
            returning = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }else{
        returning = false;
    }
});
```

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: The issue occurs within the code I provided @kleopatra

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent robot.mouseMove to generate a MouseEvent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881869/prevent-robot-mousemove-to-generate-a-mouseevent)